# Passing a dictionary with key onto a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm I little bit newbie in Python world so I don't know if I will explain it in a proper way.

I have a multithreading script in which thread function have few variables, 2 mandatory and `*args`. In `*args` I want to pass a call to a dictionary key but passing it as a variable. Let me show you the code so you can understand better:

EDIT: Proper code example

```
import threading

routers = []


def list_file(file, separator=None):
    if separator:
        return [line.strip().split(separator) for line in open(str(file), "r").readlines()]
    else:
        return [line.strip() for line in open(str(file), "r").readlines()]

def do_something(target, command, *args):
    if command == "one":
        print(target, "option one", args)
    if command == "two":
        print(target, "option two", args)
    else:
        print("No valid command")


def thread(targets, cmd, *args):
    try:
        threads = list()
        for x in targets:
            th = threading.Thread(target = cmd, args = (x["hostname"],) + args)
            threads.append(th)
            th.start()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("\n\n* Program aborted by user. Exiting...\n")
        raise


for x in list_file("./hosts.txt", ","):
    routers += [{"hostname": x[0], "dmvpn_ip": x[1]}]


thread(routers,do_something, 'one', 'hello' + x["dmvpn_ip"])
```

Basically if you see "thread(routers,do_something, 'one', 'hello' + **x["dmvpn_ip"]**)" I want to pass **x["dmvpn_ip"]** to be done in thread() in the th variable "th = threading.Thread(target = cmd, args = (x["hostname"],) + **args**)".

But it raise me the following error and if I send it as a string it doesn't do what I want:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/test.py", line 38, in <module>
    thread(routers,do_something, 'one', 'hello' + x["dmvpn_ip"])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Kind regards

Comment: I don't see anything "crazy" in your code. At the same time I don't understand what you are trying to ask.

Comment: @sid-m Is you see in the second code block, in thread call the third variable passed is x["dmvpn_ip"] but this doesn't work as it raise a TypeError (TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str) but I want to pass it as I want to read this key of the dictionary inside the for loop in thread function

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem. And, what's the actual problem?

Comment: Hi @MaxPowers I have edit the post. Let me know if the example is now valid. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I did it in another way and worked: I took out the for loop from the thread function and did it outside so I can pass directly the value of the key. Now its look like that:

```
import files
routers = []
threads = list()

for x in files.list_file("./hosts.txt", ","):
    routers += [{"hostname": x[0], "dmvpn_ip": x[1]}]

for y in routers:
    thread(threads,y['hostname'],router_cmd, 'normal', 'sh dmvpn interface ' + y['dmvpn_ip'])
```

And thread code:

```
def thread(threads, target, cmd, *args):
    try:
        th = threading.Thread(target = cmd, args = (target,) + args)
        threads.append(th)
        th.start()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("\n\n* Program aborted by user. Exiting...\n")
        raise
```